# C Binary Tree Deletion Not Working Inorder Print Causes Infinite Recursion

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I'm learning binary trees, and I'm trying to delete a node from the binary tree. I get a segmentation fault after infinite recursion in the print in order function. It only does this after the delete function is called. I don't get why this happened. I think it should only happen if the last left pointer in the tree is set to something other than NULL, which would cause the if statement to return to never be triggered. The delete function in this particular case is deleting a node on the right so it shouldn't even touch anything on the left. Help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    //blueprint for node
    int data;
    struct Node *Left;
    struct Node *Right;
};

struct Node *CreateNode(int data){
    //utility function to create a new node
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->Left = NULL;
    newNode->Right = NULL;
    newNode->data = data;
    return newNode;
}

struct Node *insertNode(struct Node *root, int num){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = CreateNode(num);
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data >= num){
        if(root->Left != NULL){
            insertNode(root->Left, num);
        }
        else{
            //if the node on the left of root is equal to NULL
            //create a node
            root->Left = CreateNode(num);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(root->Right != NULL){
            insertNode(root->Right, num);
        }
        else{
            //if the node on the right of root is equal to NULL
            //create a node
            root->Right = CreateNode(num);
        }
    }
}

void inOrderPrint(struct Node *Head){
    //prints nodes in the binary tree in order
    if(Head == NULL){
        //if the head is null, stop doing recursion
        return;
    }
        //recursivly calls itself and passes in the left node as a parameter
    if(Head->Left != NULL){
       inOrderPrint(Head->Left);
    }
        //prints out the data at the current node
        printf("%d ", Head->data);
        //recusivly calls itself and pases in the right node as a peramater
    if(Head->Right != NULL){
        inOrderPrint(Head->Right);
    }
}

int getHeight(struct Node *Head){
    //gets the height of the binary tree
    if(Head == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    int left = getHeight(Head->Left)+1;
    int right = getHeight(Head->Right) + 1;
    if(left > right){
        return left;
    }
    else{
        return right;
    }
}

int childNum(struct Node *Head){
    //returns the number of children the binary search tree node has (directly below it, not counting grand children)
    if(Head->Left == NULL && Head->Right == NULL){
        //if there is no child
        return 0;
    }
    else if(Head->Left == NULL || Head->Right == NULL){
        //if there 1 child
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        //if there are two children
        return 2;
    }
}

int getMax(struct Node *root){
    if(root->Right == NULL){
        return root->data;
    }
    else{
        return getMax(root->Right);
    }
}

struct Node *DeleteNode(struct Node *root, int num){
    //function to delete a node from the binary search tree
    if(root == NULL){
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data == num){
        //if this is the node to be deleted
        int numberOfChildren = childNum(root);
        if(numberOfChildren == 0){
            printf("here??");
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if(numberOfChildren == 1){
            if(root->Left == NULL){
                struct Node *temp = root->Right;
                free(root);
                return temp;
            }
            else{
                struct Node *temp = root->Left;
                free(root);
                return temp;
            }
        }
        else{
            int max = getMax(root->Left);
            root->data = max;
            DeleteNode(root->Left, max);
            return root;
        }
    }
    else if(root->data >= num){
        //if this node is greater than or equal to the node to be deleted, recur to the node on the left
        root->Left = DeleteNode(root->Left, num);
    }
    else{
        //if this node is less than the node to be deleted, recur to the node on rhe right
        root->Right = DeleteNode(root->Right, num);
    }
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    root = insertNode(root, 5);
    insertNode(root, 10);
    insertNode(root, 3);
    insertNode(root, 14);
    insertNode(root, 7);
    insertNode(root, 16);
    inOrderPrint(root);
    printf("\nheight: %d", getHeight(root));
    DeleteNode(root, 10);
    printf("root left: %d", root->Left->data);
    printf("\n");
    inOrderPrint(root);
    //sprintf(result, "%d/%f ...", int);

}
```

Comment: I cant replicate your issue. The program runs for me without problem.

Comment: Well that's weird. I've copy pasted it into another project and still got the same issue. idk.

Comment: What output do you get?